# Items in a list on the same line

Tags: enumerate, itemize

[image]

How to put item *b* on the same line as *a*? I tried using the command {tabular} [t] {l l c} but the *b* ends up disappearing.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide some more context to this? Are there more items than just (a) and (b)? Should there be some horizontal alignment between items on different lines (if there are multiple lines to the `enumerate`)?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the `enumitem` package and the `inline` option or alternatively at the `tasks` package.

Comment: Welcome to To TeX.SE! Please **never** add code as image, we simply can not copy and test it on our own computers to find the error. To be able to test your code it should be compilable resulting in your issue (with same error messages you got ...).

Comment: Related/duplicate [How to make horizontal lists?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/146306)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to use the `inline` option of `enumerate` or the `tasks` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate*}[label=(\alph*)]
\item first item
\item second item
\end{enumerate*}

\begin{tasks}(2)
\task first item
\task second item
\end{tasks}
\end{document}
```